# Mysqli Connection with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying so hard to make connection to mysql, and so far I end up with this error :

```
  Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost'         (using password: YES) in D:\Programs\Xamp\htdocs\series\dynamic\AtomCMS\setup.php on line 5
Could not connect because: Access denied for user 'dev'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've just started developing a new web based system and here is the code I used to make connection to the database. Any help is appreciated.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','dev','123','pouya')OR die('Could not connect because: '.mysqli_connect_error());
```

Sincerely,

Comment: can you check if the user `dev@localhost` or `dev@%` exists? and has privileges to access the database `pouya`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using XAMPP then open the phpmyadmin interface using 
                              [localhost/phpmyadmin]
1) On selecting the database you want to access.You get an option on right having a tab called privileges. 
2) You need to check whether the user exist.If not Create a user dev.If the user exist try to recreate as you may be using a wrong password.

Comment: Did it again, Same error, there are 7 privileges defined in my mysql, neither of them works with mysqli-connect function...

Comment: Can you for once use you machine IP instead of localhost and check whether it has the same issue.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the dev user exists, and that they are granted access rights to pouya.

Comment: Well, it does exists, and everything is granted.